# Can I use .htaccess to prevent direct access to files on dynamic folders?

Tags: .htaccess

I found a couple of answers where users are using htaccess to prevent direct access to some files (by using the name, extension, or folder where they are).

I'm trying to do the same but in my case, I have a script that creates subfolders dynamically under a static directory.

Eg:

```
- FolderA
  -- FolderB
  -- FolderC
  -- FolderN
```

Any file under any subfolder of FolderA shouldn't be accessed directly. I know .htaccess can take care of this. I already have php validations on session handling the correct access method (front end).

What I need is a rule that redirects the user to ROOT/index.php (if on FolderA, then it would be ../index.php) whenever he tries to access

```
FolderA/*/*.* (except index.php)
```

The ONLY file that is available directly is index.php on each subfolder.

How could I achieve this?
I'm new to htaccess and all my attemps didn't work.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: direct access? means...?

Comment: I mean, the files are private. You need a password to access the list of files. They are also named randomly. But if the user knows the name of the file, they  can type the URI and still download it without logging in.

Comment: so, protecting them by user & password is enough ?

Comment: Not really. What's protected is the front end that shows you the links to all the files. But in the case that you know the filename you will know the uri and wouldn't need to log in to download it.

Comment: sorry, could not find a solution. I'll search more tomorow

Comment: Thanks. I think it's more complicated than it seems :/

Comment: if you're using apache you can use `virtual`  function.

Comment: Is that a function I can use on the .htaccess file? The application is intented to run on IIS too, so the only way I find to do a blocking like this is an optional rules file.

Comment: no that apache specific function in php :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution, contributed by a user on a different site.

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from All
<FilesMatch "^$|(index)\.php$">
Allow from All
</FilesMatch>
```